# Send OpenCV video to another android device

Tags: java, android, opencv, video-streaming, webrtc

I'm trying to stream a video generated with OpenCV (using the webcam and doing some image processing) and audio to another android device over Internet. This will be similar to a video call with custom video frame.

I looked at WebRTC and could not find a way to send a custom image (OpenCV Mat object).

Could you suggest me any other way, any SDK or an approach to overcome this step (Client-server model) ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Serialize the Mat and send bytes! Easiest way: `imdecode` each as jpeg, and send each frame, basically an MJPEG stream.

Comment: @Miki: how do I send bytes b/w 2 android devices? setup a web server and my app will act as a client?